# Add image to 3GP file and convert it to MP4 using avconv por ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv, soundconverter

i have a `.3GP` file , i want tp add an image tp `3GP` file , then , convert this file to `MP4` ,'AVI' or even `webm` . That it means : the `audio` is from 3GP , the `image` from another file ; merge the two to have `MP4` file
How can i do it using : 
i try to convert 3GP file to mp3 file because i know how to merge MP3 file & image to get video file

```
mencoder mf://myimage.png -o out.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mjpeg -audiofile myfile.mp3 -oac copy -fps 1/187 -ofps 30
```

However this conversion does not work

```
avconv -i myfile.3gp myfile.mp3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find answer ; it is the same thing such as MP3 file , however you should use `-oac pcm` instead of `-oac copy`

```
mencoder mf://myimage.png -o out.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mjpeg -audiofile myfile.3gp -oac pcm -fps 1/187 -ofps 30
```

the output file is;

```
 out.avi
```